# I can't install modules on pip install its giving error with red text

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pypi

```
  Using cached PyQt6-6.0.0.tar.gz (579 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp7wgsb6k6'
         cwd: C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3gr2bkm6\pyqt6_c2c3ca5074ce42159b03a472b3d1254a
    Complete output (31 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 126, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        hook = backend.prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
    AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
        main()
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 263, in main
        json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 130, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        return _get_wheel_metadata_from_wheel(backend, metadata_directory,
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 159, in _get_wheel_metadata_from_wheel
        whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
      File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dj4vhhql\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\api.py", line 51, in build_wheel
        project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('pep517')
      File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dj4vhhql\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\abstract_project.py", line 83, in bootstrap
        project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
      File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dj4vhhql\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py", line 479, in setup
        self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "project.py", line 61, in apply_user_defaults
        super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dj4vhhql\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pyqtbuild\project.py", line 79, in apply_user_defaults
        super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dj4vhhql\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py", line 225, in apply_user_defaults
        self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dj4vhhql\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pyqtbuild\builder.py", line 66, in apply_user_defaults
        raise PyProjectOptionException('qmake',
    sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp7wgsb6k6' Check the logs for full command output.
```

PS: This occured when I tried to use pip install. And I tested it on other modules it gived same error.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of `pip`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare\_metadata\_for\_build\_wheel' for PyQt5 5.15.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65447314/attributeerror-module-sipbuild-api-has-no-attribute-prepare-metadata-for-bui)