# How can I run pyqt5 on my Mac with M1chip (ppc64el architecture)?

Tags: python, pyqt5, apple-m1, ppc64le

Now. When I run it. The error comes

> ImportError:
> dlopen(/Users/v/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/PyQt5/QtWidgets.abi3.so,
> 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
> /Users/v/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/PyQt5/QtWidgets.abi3.so:
> mach-o, but wrong architecture
> /Users/v/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/PyQt5/QtWidgets.abi3.so:
> mach-o, but wrong architecture

Comment: Apparently, the M1 chips are so new that Python itself doesn't know what is up with them. I heard about something called "Rosetta" that allows you to run things like on Intel Macs. Try that?

Comment: PyQt6 supports apple silicon starting from version 6.2 https://stackoverflow.com/a/75224682/19486832

Answer (score 52):

After hours of trial and error, I was finally able to solve this. My successful configuration is:

1. Open terminal with Rosetta 2 (https://dev.to/courier/tips-and-tricks-to-setup-your-apple-m1-for-development-547g)
2. Use non-homebrew python (mine was in /usr/bin/python3) to create virtual environment

```
/usr/bin/python3 -m venv env
source env/bin/activate
```

3. Upgrade pip

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

4. Install PyQt5

```
pip install PyQt5
```

Comment: Running the Terminal in Rosetta mode worked for me - Thanks

Comment: Was trying to get this working from a day! damn, thanks mate :)

Comment: This worked for me. Why doesn't python installed via homebrew work?

Comment: If it’s installed with Rosetta, will it still work with native M1 python? I just got my m1 MacBook Pro a few days ago so apologies if this is a dumb question.

Comment: Please give this guy a medal.

Comment: @AffableAmbler I was thinking the same.

These steps can be followed; although if you do not want to always have your terminal open in Rosetta, or if you just have some one-off commands, you can prepend `arch -x86_64` to any command that needs Rosetta. So, my steps would have been:

`virtualenv env`  (or whatever env you like),  `source env/bin/activate`, `arch -x86_64 pip install PyQt5`, and then when you want to run whatever program you are writing, `arch x86_64 my_wicket_program.py`

Comment: The key for me was step 2. If you use the brew version it still breaks.

Comment: Thanks @AxelJacobsen, this saved my lot of time. arch -x86_64 is important here.

Answer (score 18):

I needed PyQt5 as a dependency for a Python library and this worked for me. See original post [here](https://www.zhihu.com/question/437075754/answer/1993415429).

```
brew install pyqt5
echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/qt@5/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/pyqt@5/5.15.4_1/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
source ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: I also added: `export PYTHONPATH=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/pyqt@5/5.15.7/lib/python3.9/site-packages` to my ~/.zshrc

Answer (score 14):

What I ended up doing specifically for `pyqt5` was:

```bash
brew install pyqt@5
```

I think for versions 4 and 6 this may work as well. When I went simply `brew install pyqt` that didn't work unfortunately.

*note this is M1 Macbook only*

One other thing to try as things settle down with M1s is to try `pip3 install pyqt5` in a terminal launched in Rosetta mode (left click -> Get Info -> Open in Rosetta)

**Edit (Nov 2022)**

It seems that if you don't specifically need pyqt5, pyqt6 is now easily installable via pip on M1/M2 Macs.

```bash
python -m pip install pyqt6
```

Comment: I'm installing a package that uses PyQt5. I was able to run `brew install pyqt@5` but the installation still fails on `Collecting PyQt5==5.15.2`

Comment: @JeffBezos perhaps removing that requirement from package dependencies would skip installing it? It may work with the version you installed via brew.

Comment: error: metadata-generation-failed

Comment: but still, when I run `pip list --outdated | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -n1 sh -c 'pip install -U "$@" | tee -a upgrade.log' sh` to update all packages, it looks for pyqt5! which stuck on `Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started`

Answer (score 6):

I was hoping to install pyqt5 on my M1 mac *without* Rosetta. I was using it as a dependency of another project that I wanted to install in a venv which requires pyqt5 and was not installable via pipx (`urh`).

Unfortunately, there currently are no compatible wheels (`curl --silent "https://pypi.org/pypi/PyQt5/json" | grep -i arm64`), and attempting to install on 3.10 fails with `AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'`

Thankfully, the homebrew installation of pyqt5 is compiled for arm64 and works well.

My steps were:

```bash
$ # Install pyqt5 via homebrew
$ brew install pyqt@5
$ # Note that it's installed in python3.9, not 3.10
$ brew cat pyqt@5 | grep 'depends_on.*python'
  depends_on "python@3.9"
$ # Make a python3.9 virtualenv with access to the system's site-packages
$ /opt/homebrew/bin/python3.9 -m venv --system-site-packages .venv
$ source .venv/bin/activate
```

At this point I was able to install `urh` into the virtualenv, using the arm64-compiled pyqt5 from hombrew, without neededing Rosetta (and without needing to further "pollute" my system site-packages), and it runs as expected (since the question was about *running*).

Comment: This one worked for me using python3.9, trying to pip3.9 install office365.  I think --system-site-packages may have been key here.

Comment: this is the only one that worked for me and it was the easiest once as well.  Should be marked as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try installing the pyqt under the ARM architecture as below

`arch -arm64 brew install pyqt`

Answer (score 2):

You can use it from homebrew, this is the only way I found it working on Mac M1.

First:

```
  brew install pyqt@5
```

Then:

```
brew --cellar
brew link --overwrite python
```

Then you must create/add an alias for python and put it in your .zprofile (Located in Users/username folder, if you press Shift+command+.

This must point to your homebrew python installation location.

```
alias python ='opt/homebrew/bin/python3'
```

That way it will link python with your homebrew python and you can run python test.py from terminal (Where your python files are located).
No matter how I tried with pip install, it just shown error and did not work.

Answer (score 2):

I had to install `PyQt5==5.15.6`on my MacM1 into an existing virtual environment.

It did not work using all the methods described here.

So, what I did is :

1. [Open the terminal in rosetta mode](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/428768/on-apple-m1-with-rosetta-how-to-open-entire-terminal-iterm-in-x86-64-architec)
2. Navigate to my project and activate the virtual environment `source venv/bin/activate`
3. Install the package : `pip install PyQt5==5.15.6`
4. Open a regular terminal into my project and make sure everything was installed as per the requirements.txt : `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Everything is running smoothly, now.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it's work:    `arch -x86_64 brew install pyqt`
And all required pyqt start from arch -x86_64 or start from rosetta (through emulator).

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to run PyQt5 under virtual environment with Python3.6.
The following procedures worked for me.

My settings are MBA M1 2020, macOS 11.3.1, and

```
pyenv versions
>   system
> * 3.6.15
pip -V
> pip 21.3.1 from /Users/username/.pyenv/versions/3.6.15/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

Then simply run:

```
pip install pyqt5-sip
pip install pyqt5
```

on the terminal (default one, not the one with Rosetta 2).

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still having the same problem with installation of PyQT5, I would suggest you to rather lock your focus on PySide6. It is 99% similar to PyQT5 and works well with MacBook m1.

I've been digging the Internet for hours hoping to find the solution but it appears that PyQT5 and PyQT5-tools modules are somewhat broken on MacBook M1 when it comes to downloading them.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with installing PyQt5 on M1 mac with MacOS 12.6 (Monterey) inside a virtual environment (using python 3.9). The final solution that worked for me was to use conda for creating and activating the virtual environment.

`conda create --name venv python=3.9` `conda activate venv`

And then simply using conda to install PyQt5 as part of the pyqt package.

`conda install pyqt`

Answer (score 1):

**PyQt6 is out now and supports apple silicon:**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/75224682/19486832

No conda support, but pip install is working fine:

```
python -m pip install PyQt6
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just upgrade to PySide6. It's the official library, and it was actually easier for me than upgrading to PyQT6 since we have a `pyside6-rcc` command so you can use your `.qrc` files as is. PyQT6 dropped `pyrcc6`.