# How to install PyQt5 on MacOS?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt

I try to install PyQt in my Mac by pip or brew to install, it all failed with `sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException` error. Need help can someone solve this?

```
jett@jmac ~ % pip install pyqt5
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pyqt5
  Using cached PyQt5-5.15.4.tar.gz (3.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3 /Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/tmpgdmdc09l
         cwd: /private/var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/pip-install-bv0c7yxz/pyqt5_7923519b6ae5437192ce4b58d6719383
    Complete output (31 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 126, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        hook = backend.prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
    AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
        main()
      File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 263, in main
        json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
      File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 130, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        return _get_wheel_metadata_from_wheel(backend, metadata_directory,
      File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 159, in _get_wheel_metadata_from_wheel
        whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
      File "/private/var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/pip-build-env-4yn2ftzm/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sipbuild/api.py", line 51, in build_wheel
        project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('pep517')
      File "/private/var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/pip-build-env-4yn2ftzm/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sipbuild/abstract_project.py", line 83, in bootstrap
        project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
      File "/private/var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/pip-build-env-4yn2ftzm/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 484, in setup
        self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "project.py", line 63, in apply_user_defaults
        super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "/private/var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/pip-build-env-4yn2ftzm/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyqtbuild/project.py", line 70, in apply_user_defaults
        super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "/private/var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/pip-build-env-4yn2ftzm/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 230, in apply_user_defaults
        self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "/private/var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/pip-build-env-4yn2ftzm/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyqtbuild/builder.py", line 66, in apply_user_defaults
        raise PyProjectOptionException('qmake',
    sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8e/a4/d5e4bf99dd50134c88b95e926d7b81aad2473b47fde5e3e4eac2c69a8942/PyQt5-5.15.4.tar.gz#sha256=2a69597e0dd11caabe75fae133feca66387819fc9bc050f547e5551bce97e5be (from https://pypi.org/simple/pyqt5/) (requires-python:>=3.6). Command errored out with exit status 1: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3 /Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/tmpgdmdc09l Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached PyQt5-5.15.3.tar.gz (3.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3 /Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/tmp2b3zk776
         cwd: /private/var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/pip-install-bv0c7yxz/pyqt5_44052bd6cdc34aa2be5b23f36dca88df
    Complete output (31 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 126, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        hook = backend.prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
    AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
        main()
      File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 263, in main
        json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
      File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 130, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        return _get_wheel_metadata_from_wheel(backend, metadata_directory,
      File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 159, in _get_wheel_metadata_from_wheel
        whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
      File "/private/var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/pip-build-env-cx5p34wp/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sipbuild/api.py", line 51, in build_wheel
        project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('pep517')
      File "/private/var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/pip-build-env-cx5p34wp/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sipbuild/abstract_project.py", line 83, in bootstrap
        project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
      File "/private/var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/pip-build-env-cx5p34wp/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 484, in setup
        self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "project.py", line 63, in apply_user_defaults
        super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "/private/var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/pip-build-env-cx5p34wp/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyqtbuild/project.py", line 70, in apply_user_defaults
        super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "/private/var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/pip-build-env-cx5p34wp/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 230, in apply_user_defaults
        self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "/private/var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/pip-build-env-cx5p34wp/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyqtbuild/builder.py", line 66, in apply_user_defaults
        raise PyProjectOptionException('qmake',
    sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6e/86/d715e71771cece0e060f2ebab20f3ded067b08a0927dfb3143530cae8098/PyQt5-5.15.3.tar.gz#sha256=965ba50e7029b37f218a54ace24e87c77db3e5a9f0b83baeb21fb57b4154b838 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pyqt5/) (requires-python:>=3.6). Command errored out with exit status 1: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3 /Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/tmp2b3zk776 Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached PyQt5-5.15.2.tar.gz (3.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3 /Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/tmp_r170a4s
         cwd: /private/var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/pip-install-bv0c7yxz/pyqt5_7cbcbc9529f7468180a67bbd9372be5b
    Complete output (31 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 126, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        hook = backend.prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
    AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
        main()
      File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 263, in main
        json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
      File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 130, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        return _get_wheel_metadata_from_wheel(backend, metadata_directory,
      File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 159, in _get_wheel_metadata_from_wheel
        whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
      File "/private/var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/pip-build-env-hihu6t3f/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sipbuild/api.py", line 51, in build_wheel
        project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('pep517')
      File "/private/var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/pip-build-env-hihu6t3f/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sipbuild/abstract_project.py", line 83, in bootstrap
        project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
      File "/private/var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/pip-build-env-hihu6t3f/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 484, in setup
        self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "project.py", line 63, in apply_user_defaults
        super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "/private/var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/pip-build-env-hihu6t3f/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyqtbuild/project.py", line 70, in apply_user_defaults
        super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "/private/var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/pip-build-env-hihu6t3f/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 230, in apply_user_defaults
        self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "/private/var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/pip-build-env-hihu6t3f/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyqtbuild/builder.py", line 66, in apply_user_defaults
        raise PyProjectOptionException('qmake',
    sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/28/6c/640e3f5c734c296a7193079a86842a789edb7988dca39eab44579088a1d1/PyQt5-5.15.2.tar.gz#sha256=372b08dc9321d1201e4690182697c5e7ffb2e0770e6b4a45519025134b12e4fc (from https://pypi.org/simple/pyqt5/) (requires-python:>=3.5). Command errored out with exit status 1: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3 /Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/tmp_r170a4s Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached PyQt5-5.15.1.tar.gz (3.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3 /Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/tmprj4uldbh
         cwd: /private/var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/pip-install-bv0c7yxz/pyqt5_b03b2a05214c4d1ebc157f6b7a32e368
    Complete output (31 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 126, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        hook = backend.prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
    AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
        main()
      File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 263, in main
        json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
      File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 130, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        return _get_wheel_metadata_from_wheel(backend, metadata_directory,
      File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 159, in _get_wheel_metadata_from_wheel
        whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
      File "/private/var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/pip-build-env-np1hm2fb/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sipbuild/api.py", line 51, in build_wheel
        project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('pep517')
      File "/private/var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/pip-build-env-np1hm2fb/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sipbuild/abstract_project.py", line 83, in bootstrap
        project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
      File "/private/var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/pip-build-env-np1hm2fb/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 484, in setup
        self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "project.py", line 64, in apply_user_defaults
        super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "/private/var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/pip-build-env-np1hm2fb/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyqtbuild/project.py", line 70, in apply_user_defaults
        super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "/private/var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/pip-build-env-np1hm2fb/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 230, in apply_user_defaults
        self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "/private/var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/pip-build-env-np1hm2fb/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyqtbuild/builder.py", line 66, in apply_user_defaults
        raise PyProjectOptionException('qmake',
    sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1d/31/896dc3dfb6c81c70164019a6cbba6ab037e3af7653d9ca60ccc874ee4c27/PyQt5-5.15.1.tar.gz#sha256=d9a76b850246d08da9863189ecb98f6c2aa9b4d97a3e85e29330a264aed0f9a1 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pyqt5/) (requires-python:>=3.5). Command errored out with exit status 1: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3 /Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/tmprj4uldbh Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached PyQt5-5.15.0.tar.gz (3.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3 /Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/tmp3ql7xuy2
         cwd: /private/var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/pip-install-bv0c7yxz/pyqt5_688200d6210b451b8a4ab6479b451a89
    Complete output (31 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 126, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        hook = backend.prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
    AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
        main()
      File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 263, in main
        json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
      File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 130, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        return _get_wheel_metadata_from_wheel(backend, metadata_directory,
      File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 159, in _get_wheel_metadata_from_wheel
        whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
      File "/private/var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/pip-build-env-o6cj0zt7/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sipbuild/api.py", line 51, in build_wheel
        project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('pep517')
      File "/private/var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/pip-build-env-o6cj0zt7/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sipbuild/abstract_project.py", line 83, in bootstrap
        project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
      File "/private/var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/pip-build-env-o6cj0zt7/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 484, in setup
        self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "project.py", line 62, in apply_user_defaults
        super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "/private/var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/pip-build-env-o6cj0zt7/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyqtbuild/project.py", line 70, in apply_user_defaults
        super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "/private/var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/pip-build-env-o6cj0zt7/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 230, in apply_user_defaults
        self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "/private/var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/pip-build-env-o6cj0zt7/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyqtbuild/builder.py", line 66, in apply_user_defaults
        raise PyProjectOptionException('qmake',
    sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8c/90/82c62bbbadcca98e8c6fa84f1a638de1ed1c89e85368241e9cc43fcbc320/PyQt5-5.15.0.tar.gz#sha256=c6f75488ffd5365a65893bc64ea82a6957db126fbfe33654bcd43ae1c30c52f9 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pyqt5/) (requires-python:>=3.5). Command errored out with exit status 1: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3 /Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/tmp3ql7xuy2 Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached PyQt5-5.14.2.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3 /Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/tmp9oeqr7vm
         cwd: /private/var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/pip-install-bv0c7yxz/pyqt5_f8c59757cc3e421eb7323c1e0166ff3d
    Complete output (31 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 126, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        hook = backend.prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
    AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
        main()
      File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 263, in main
        json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
      File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 130, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        return _get_wheel_metadata_from_wheel(backend, metadata_directory,
      File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 159, in _get_wheel_metadata_from_wheel
        whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
      File "/private/var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/pip-build-env-6w6xra03/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sipbuild/api.py", line 51, in build_wheel
        project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('pep517')
      File "/private/var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/pip-build-env-6w6xra03/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sipbuild/abstract_project.py", line 83, in bootstrap
        project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
      File "/private/var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/pip-build-env-6w6xra03/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 479, in setup
        self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "project.py", line 62, in apply_user_defaults
        super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "/private/var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/pip-build-env-6w6xra03/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyqtbuild/project.py", line 70, in apply_user_defaults
        super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "/private/var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/pip-build-env-6w6xra03/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 225, in apply_user_defaults
        self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "/private/var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/pip-build-env-6w6xra03/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyqtbuild/builder.py", line 66, in apply_user_defaults
        raise PyProjectOptionException('qmake',
    sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4d/81/b9a66a28fb9a7bbeb60e266f06ebc4703e7e42b99e3609bf1b58ddd232b9/PyQt5-5.14.2.tar.gz#sha256=bd230c6fd699eabf1ceb51e13a8b79b74c00a80272c622427b80141a22269eb0 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pyqt5/) (requires-python:>=3.5). Command errored out with exit status 1: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3 /Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/tmp9oeqr7vm Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached PyQt5-5.14.1.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3 /Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/tmpgyk62cud
         cwd: /private/var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/pip-install-bv0c7yxz/pyqt5_561782674bb34431a57220b8c2e76631
    Complete output (31 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 126, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        hook = backend.prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
    AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
        main()
      File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 263, in main
        json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
      File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 130, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        return _get_wheel_metadata_from_wheel(backend, metadata_directory,
      File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 159, in _get_wheel_metadata_from_wheel
        whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
      File "/private/var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/pip-build-env-bdif8fjh/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sipbuild/api.py", line 51, in build_wheel
        project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('pep517')
      File "/private/var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/pip-build-env-bdif8fjh/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sipbuild/abstract_project.py", line 83, in bootstrap
        project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
      File "/private/var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/pip-build-env-bdif8fjh/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 479, in setup
        self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "project.py", line 62, in apply_user_defaults
        super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "/private/var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/pip-build-env-bdif8fjh/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyqtbuild/project.py", line 70, in apply_user_defaults
        super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "/private/var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/pip-build-env-bdif8fjh/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 225, in apply_user_defaults
        self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "/private/var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/pip-build-env-bdif8fjh/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyqtbuild/builder.py", line 66, in apply_user_defaults
        raise PyProjectOptionException('qmake',
    sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3a/fb/eb51731f2dc7c22d8e1a63ba88fb702727b324c6352183a32f27f73b8116/PyQt5-5.14.1.tar.gz#sha256=2f230f2dbd767099de7a0cb915abdf0cbc3256a0b5bb910eb09b99117db7a65b (from https://pypi.org/simple/pyqt5/) (requires-python:>=3.5). Command errored out with exit status 1: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3 /Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /var/folders/kk/ck6hb36n5z1373zlhm46l3m80000gn/T/tmpgyk62cud Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached PyQt5-5.14.0.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
ERROR: pyqt5 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7c/5b/e760ec4f868cb77cee45b4554bf15d3fe6972176e89c4e3faac941213694/PyQt5-5.14.0.tar.gz#sha256=0145a6b7de15756366decb736c349a0cb510d706c83fda5b8cd9e0557bc1da72 has a pyproject.toml file that does not comply with PEP 518: 'build-system.requires' contains an invalid requirement: 'sip >=5.0.1 <6'
jett@jmac ~ %
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you using an M1 Mac? If so, this worked for me: [How can i run pyqt5 on my mac with M1chip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65901162/how-can-i-run-pyqt5-on-my-mac-with-m1chip)

In case that page gets removed and someone needs this:

1. Right click the Terminal application in Finder, click duplicate.
2. Rename one of them so you know which is which.
3. Right click the renamed one, and click "Get Info". Check the option "Open using Rosetta"
4. Open the Rosetta version, create a virtual Python environment. `/usr/bin/python3 -m venv env`
5. Activate the environment. `source env/bin/activate`
6. Upgrade pip `pip install --upgrade pip`
7. Install PyQt5 `pip install PyQt5`

This worked for me on an M1 Air running Big Sur, I can't say if it helps on Intel Macs.

Comment: This answer is a workaround, not a real solution. A complete solution would not require the use of Rosetta.

Answer (score 2):

answer from Mike Simone worked for me except for step 7, which failed using pyqt5, but was successful using pyqt6.

pyqt6 installed for ARM, as seen from the output below.

In code simply change your imports to PyQt6. There are some minor code differences.

```
(venv) username@MacPunch pushbutton % pip install PyQt6
Collecting PyQt6
  Downloading PyQt6-6.4.0-cp37-abi3-macosx_10_14_universal2.whl (11.6 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 11.6/11.6 MB 3.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting PyQt6-Qt6>=6.4.0
  Downloading PyQt6_Qt6-6.4.1-py3-none-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (38.0 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 38.0/38.0 MB 2.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting PyQt6-sip<14,>=13.4
  Downloading PyQt6_sip-13.4.0.tar.gz (111 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 111.2/111.2 kB 2.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: PyQt6-sip
  Building wheel for PyQt6-sip (pyproject.toml) ... done
  Created wheel for PyQt6-sip: filename=PyQt6_sip-13.4.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_14_arm64.whl size=132021 sha256=871d16c4c852b49b9d4859ece2d516a4e650fe10a0024f9bf7105773b5ad0be9
  Stored in directory: /Users/username/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/98/43/59/58c7e4bf0439947e465446a8948e84910729052c76131272e8
Successfully built PyQt6-sip
Installing collected packages: PyQt6-Qt6, PyQt6-sip, PyQt6
Successfully installed PyQt6-6.4.0 PyQt6-Qt6-6.4.1 PyQt6-sip-13.4.0
(venv) username@MacPunch pushbutton %
```

Comment: pyqt6 now had arm version.

Answer (score 0):

The chosen answer has pretty much says it all, and it solved mine too. Just a side note, the virtual environment must be created from the system python located `/usr/bin/python3`, other pythons won't work.