# i can't install pyqt5 tools on python 3.10 can anyone explain whats the problem is ? here is the error

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

```
ERROR: pyqt5==5.14.0 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7c/5b/e760ec4f868cb77cee45b4554bf15d3fe6972176e89c4e3faac941213694/PyQt5-5.14.0.tar.gz#sha256=0145a6b7de15756366decb736c349a0cb510d706c83fda5b8cd9e0557bc1da72 (from pyqt5-tools) has a pyproject.toml file that does not comply with PEP 518: 'build-system.requires' contains an invalid requirement: 'sip >=5.0.1 <6'
```

Comment: Seems to be the same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68317410/how-to-install-pyqt5-on-macos

Comment: yeah it is pretty simillar isn't it? do you know the solution ?

Comment: According to [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pyqt5-tools/), python-3.10 isn't explicitly supported yet. It also states that "MacOS support is incomplete" - but exactly what that means is unclear. It seems odd that pyqt-5.14.0 is being used, when the latest version is 5.15.5. What *specific* command did you use to try to install pyqt5-tools?