# Unable to install PyQt5 with pip

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, apple-m1

Im running into a problem installing PyQt5 with pip:

```
pip install pyqt5

DEPRECATION: Configuring installation scheme with distutils config files is deprecated and will no longer work in the near future. If you are using a Homebrew or Linuxbrew Python, please see discussion at https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/76621
    Collecting pyqt5
      Using cached PyQt5-5.15.6.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
      Installing build dependencies ... done
      Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
      Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9 /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /var/folders/rv/nylh_sjx44b1bq2pmbn1lwkr0000gn/T/tmpi8zk3o59
           cwd: /private/var/folders/rv/nylh_sjx44b1bq2pmbn1lwkr0000gn/T/pip-install-9w2kcz7l/pyqt5_a170d636f15d43c8bb4ae5d9a73574fc
      Complete output (24 lines):
      Querying qmake about your Qt installation...
      /opt/homebrew/bin/qmake -query
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 156, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          hook = backend.prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
      AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'
    
      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
          main()
        File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 345, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 160, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
        File "/private/var/folders/rv/nylh_sjx44b1bq2pmbn1lwkr0000gn/T/pip-build-env-fyh98wta/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sipbuild/api.py", line 51, in build_wheel
          project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('pep517')
        File "/private/var/folders/rv/nylh_sjx44b1bq2pmbn1lwkr0000gn/T/pip-build-env-fyh98wta/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sipbuild/abstract_project.py", line 83, in bootstrap
          project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
        File "/private/var/folders/rv/nylh_sjx44b1bq2pmbn1lwkr0000gn/T/pip-build-env-fyh98wta/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 603, in setup
          self.update(tool)
        File "project.py", line 160, in update
      sipbuild.exceptions.UserException
      ----------------------------------------
```

Im using macOS Monterey 12.0.1, with the Apple M1 chip.

What I've tried so far:

- Installed PyQt5 using homebrew. Result: PyQt5 got installed via brew but without the necessary package PyQtWebengine. Means when I try to run my application, I receive the error message, that PyQtWebengine package/module is not installed which Im not able to install with pip. So I uninstalled it.
- Installed sip and uninstalled
- qt (6.2.2) and qt@5 (5.15.2) are installed with brew
- Run cmd: python3 -m pip install PyQt5
- Pip is up to date (21.3.1)
- pip install with a specific PyQt5 Version

Any ideas to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance for any ideas/solutions!

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65901162/how-can-i-run-pyqt5-on-my-mac-with-m1chip/72363627#72363627, which was asked first and has many more views, but this was asked with so much more information I'm inclined not to flag as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

The way I solved the same problem in my M1s was installing the library via terminal launched in Rosetta mode (left click on the Terminal icon -> Get Info -> Open in Rosetta).

So, detailed steps are:

1. Open a Terminal with Rosetta 2 via left click on the Terminal icon -> Get Info -> Open in Rosetta (https://dev.to/courier/tips-and-tricks-to-setup-your-apple-m1-for-development-547g)
2. Use non-homebrew python (mine was in /usr/bin/python3) to create virtual environment

```
$ /usr/bin/python3 -m venv venv
$ source venv/bin/activate
```

3. Upgrade pip

```
(venv)$ pip install --upgrade pip
```

4. Install PyQt5

```
(venv) $pip install PyQt5
```

Alternatively, you can do a one-off installation via this command:

```
$ arch -x86_64 python -m pip install PyQt5
```

Comment: This made me run into incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e') errors :-/

Answer (score 1):

I use macos 12.1 (m1), and I use `mini-forge` with homebrew, I have installed `pyqt5` with `conda install pyqt`.

P.S. my python version is 3.9.

Answer (score 1):

As I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72363627/1588795), Rosetta is not required if you're willing to use Homebrew's pyqt@5. Homebrew includes an arm64-compiled pyqt5, and one can leverage its installation in a venv using the `--system-site-packages` flag to `venv`:

```
$ # Install pyqt5 via homebrew
$ brew install pyqt@5
$ # Note that it's installed in python3.9, not 3.10
$ brew cat pyqt@5 | grep 'depends_on.*python'
  depends_on "python@3.9"
$ # Make a python3.9 virtualenv with access to the system's site-packages
$ /opt/homebrew/bin/python3.9 -m venv --system-site-packages .venv
$ source .venv/bin/activate
```

Answer (score 1):

```
conda create -n py3.9.13 python=3.9.13
conda install pyqt
```

Worked for me. I'm using macOS Monterey 12.4, with the Apple M1 chip. `Anaconda3` installed many dependences automatically while installing. After the above installation, my `conda list`:

```
# Name                          Version
bzip2                           1.0.8
ca-certificates                 2022.6.15
gettext                         0.19.8.1
glib                            2.70.2
glib-tools                      2.70.2
gst-plugins-base                1.20.3
gstreamer                       1.20.3
icu                             70.1
jpeg                            9e
krb5                            1.19.3
libclang                        14.0.6
libclang13                      14.0.6
libcxx                          14.0.6
libedit                         3.1.20191231
libffi                          3.4.2
libglib                         2.70.2
libiconv                        1.16
libllvm14                       14.0.6
libogg                          1.3.4
libopus                         1.3.1
libpng                          1.6.37
libpq                           14.4
libvorbis                       1.3.7
libzlib                         1.2.12
lz4-c                           1.9.3
mysql-common                    8.0.29
mysql-libs                      8.0.29
ncurses                         6.3
nspr                            4.32
nss                             3.78
openssl                         1.1.1p
packaging                       21.3
pcre                            8.45
pip                             22.1.2
ply                             3.11
pyparsing                       3.0.9
pyqt                            5.15.4
pyqt5-sip                       12.9.0
python                          3.9.13
python_abi                      3.9
qt-main                         5.15.4
readline                        8.1.2
setuptools                      62.6.0
sip                             6.6.2
sqlite                          3.39.0
tk                              8.6.12
toml                            0.10.2
tzdata                          2022a
wheel                           0.37.1
xz                              5.2.5
zlib                            1.2.12
zstd                            1.5.2
```