# Configure poetry to create x86 environment

Tags: development-environment, python-poetry

## TLDR

How can I configure `poetry` to use/create an `x86` environment?

## Details

My python project has a dependency that is not available for apple silicon (I use a Macbook Pro M2). A plain `pip install` will run into an error:

```bash
installing pyqt-qt5 (5.15.2): Failed
RuntimeError
Unable to find installation candidates for pyqt-qt5 (5.15.2)
```

### What works

Using `conda` to handle the virtual environment, I can enforce the `x86` version of the dependencies like so:

```bash
CONDA_SUBDIR=osx-64 conda create -n my-intel-env python=3.11 -y
conda activate my-intel-env
conda env config vars set CONDA_SUBDIR=osx-64
conda deactivate
conda activate my-intel-env
pip install "poetry==1.5.1"
poetry install --with dev
```

```bash
...
  • Installing pymiscutils (0.3.14)
  • Installing pyqt5 (5.15.9)
  • Installing requests-oauthlib (1.3.1)
...
```

### What doesn't

However, I'd like to ditch `conda` and use `poetry` exclusively, i.e., *also for creating the venv*. For this, I have a `poetry.toml` file in the project root:

```ini
[virtualenvs]
in-project = true
```

When running `poetry install` while not having a venv activated, this will create a `.venv` folder inside the project root, and install all dependencies into it, which is what I want. However, it fails in the same way as described at the top.

**How can I configure `poetry` to use `x86`, similarly to how I did it for `conda`?**

[full disclosure: I posted this question also on AskDifferent, but it's more of a poetry question than a mac question, so I decided to repost here]

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to have a [`pyproject.toml` file](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/) set up in the project root.

Once you have that, you can use the [Poetry CLI](https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#add) to add and install the desired package, specifying the target platform(s):

```bash
# Adding one target platform
poetry add --platform "win32" requests
# or
poetry add --platform="win32" requests

# Adding multiple target platforms
poetry add --platform "win32 || linux" requests
# or
poetry add --platform="win32 || linux" requests
```

The valid platform values are what you would find from the `sys_platform` [environment marker](https://peps.python.org/pep-0508/#environment-markers).
In the case of a Windows environment, that would be `win32`.

Running the add command will update the `[tool.poetry.dependencies]` in your `pyproject.toml file` and add the specified package:

```ini
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
requests = {version = "^2.31.0", platform = "win32 || linux"}
```

Alternatively, you can use [environment markers](https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#python-restricted-dependencies) directly.

Comment: Thank you @M69k65y. Is there a way to find out, which dependency I should request to have `win32`? Poetry is trying to install `pyqt5-qt5`, but it's not an explicit dependency of my project - rather, it's a dependency of (a dependency of...) a dependency.

Comment: Since `pyqt5-qt5` is not a direct dependency, I can't think of a way right now to do that and the docs don't seem to have anything promising right now.  
The closest I could think of right now is running `python add --dry-run -vvv <package>` to see what other packages would be installed.  
Alternatively, set the parent dependency to fetch the `win32` version.

Comment: Thanks for that. I looked into getting a dependency tree from poetry, but was ultimately unsuccessful. I then tried explicitly stating `poetry add --platform "win32" pyqt5-qt5`, but I'm receiving the same error as before ("`unable to find installation candidate`")

Comment: Perhaps [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70248787/unable-to-install-pyqt5-with-pip) might help you with your installation problem. It would allow you to use Poetry without `conda` and you likely won't need to specify target platforms either.