# `pyqt5' error `metadata-generation-failed`

Tags: python, macos, pip, pyqt5, homebrew

I am trying to install `pyqt5` using mac OS with the M1 chip and Python 3.9.12. I suspect the M1 chip may be the cause.

I get an error `metadata-generation-failed`.

**minimum working example**

```
# directly in the terminal
pip install --no-cache-dir PyQt5==5.14.1
```

or by adding the line below to a `requirements.txt`

```
# necessary for jupyter-notebook so added to requirements.txt
# then run: pip install -r requirements.txt
pyqt5==5.14.1 # missing in conda-forge
```

**my attempts**

I also tried using the solutions below but non worked. Homebrew also claimed that pyqt was installed which was strange.

1. `pip install pyqt5`
2. `brew install pyqt5`
3. adding it to `requirements.txt` then running `pip install -r requirements.txt`

**related questions**:

- [AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel' for PyQt5 5.15.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65447314/attributeerror-module-sipbuild-api-has-no-attribute-prepare-metadata-for-bui)

Answer (score 1):

This might really be a M1 issue.
I think this is a similar issue to yours: [How can i run pyqt5 on my mac with M1chip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65901162/how-can-i-run-pyqt5-on-my-mac-with-m1chip)

But it might be a better solution to just build the PyQt5 package from source:
[Building PyQt5 from Source](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/installation.html#building-and-installing-from-source)

I also found this script where someone builds and installs PyQt6 on a M1 Mac: [Build PyQt6 on M1](https://gist.github.com/jinwoo1225/a6bef23bdacb4dee6fbfe50301f2f670).
This script can be altered to build PyQt5.

EDIT: Consider using PyQt6 (`pip install PyQt6`). It already has a universal2 build on pypi.

Answer (score 0):

For troubleshooting purposes, can you run :

```
# Make sure python3 points to your Python 3.9.12
python3 -m venv /tmp/venv
source /tmp/venv/bin/activate
pip install --no-cache-dir PyQt5==5.14.1
# If last step fails and complains about `pip` version, upgrade `pip` and try `pip install ..` again
```

If PyQt5 is installed successfully, then you are sure it's not a problem of M1 chip. Then you can try :

```
python3 -m pip install --no-cache-dir PyQt5==5.14.1
```

Comment: Thanks @Phillippe , this did not work though. I got the same error message.