# Issues with pip installing PyQt5 in conda on M2 MacBook

Tags: python, pyqt5, conda, apple-m1

I am currently trying to use pip to install a package, but it stops when installing PyQt5. I am using an Anaconda Navigator environment per the installer's instructions (https://www.sams-xrays.com/install-smak).

1. Install Anaconda Navigator from the website
2. Create a new environment

   ```
   conda create -n smakenv python==3.10
   ```
3. Activate new environment

   ```
   conda activate smakenv
   ```
4. install program

   ```
   conda activate smakenv
   ```

This installation stalls when trying to install PyQt5 with the error:

```
(smakenv) Mirandas-MBP-2:~ miranda$ pip install PyQt5
Collecting PyQt5
  Using cached PyQt5-5.15.10.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [17 lines of output]
      Querying qmake about your Qt installation...
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Users/miranda/anaconda3/envs/smakenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/Users/miranda/anaconda3/envs/smakenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/Users/miranda/anaconda3/envs/smakenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 152, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
        File "/private/var/folders/s6/00ws0jr51770fkljkphkmfc80000gn/T/pip-build-env-gt_l3opo/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sipbuild/api.py", line 46, in build_wheel
          project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('wheel',
        File "/private/var/folders/s6/00ws0jr51770fkljkphkmfc80000gn/T/pip-build-env-gt_l3opo/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sipbuild/abstract_project.py", line 87, in bootstrap
          project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
        File "/private/var/folders/s6/00ws0jr51770fkljkphkmfc80000gn/T/pip-build-env-gt_l3opo/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 602, in setup
          self.update(tool)
        File "/private/var/folders/s6/00ws0jr51770fkljkphkmfc80000gn/T/pip-install-jcfb2swp/pyqt5_a3845a406fd041b68c46d756b6ce117d/project.py", line 165, in update
          raise UserException(
      sipbuild.exceptions.UserException
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.
```

I have tried various things to get PyQt to install, none of which have worked:

1. Home-brew: Could not successfully integrate this into the Anaconda virtual environment
2. Rosetta terminal ([How can I run pyqt5 on my Mac with M1chip (ppc64el architecture)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65901162/how-can-i-run-pyqt5-on-my-mac-with-m1chip-ppc64el-architecture)) - this successfully downloaded PyQt5, but I could not successfully run the software (GUI did not show up) even when running python v3.10 as specified when setting up the Anaconda virtual environment.

I have a Macbook M2, running Monterey 12.5 and I am using Anaconda Navigator v2.5. The virtual environment has installed pip v23.3.

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: PyQt5 didn't support Apple Silicon until recently. Check their [local server](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pypi/) for the updated wheels (which are still considered experimental) or wait for the official release on pypi.