# Pyqt5 not installing

Tags: python, pyqt5

So basically ive been trying to install pyqt5 using pip in visual studio code and it  always comes back with this error preparing wheel metadata... Error

```
 Using cached PyQt5-5.14.1.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\97152\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' 'C:\Users\97152\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\97152\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpzk3hpkso'
         cwd: C:\Users\97152\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n92hbnur\pyqt5_823c0736297343559d66d8215f79e2c8 
    Complete output (29 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\97152\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 143, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        hook = backend.prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
    AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\97152\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 349, in <module>
        main()
      File "C:\Users\97152\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 331, in main 
        json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
      File "C:\Users\97152\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 147, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
      File "C:\Users\97152\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-5j8h2xca\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\api.py", line 51, in build_wheel
        project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('pep517')
      File "C:\Users\97152\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-5j8h2xca\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\abstract_project.py", line 83, in bootstrap
        project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
      File "C:\Users\97152\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-5j8h2xca\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py", line 479, in setup
        self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "C:\Users\97152\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n92hbnur\pyqt5_823c0736297343559d66d8215f79e2c8\project.py", line 62, in apply_user_defaults
        super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "C:\Users\97152\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-5j8h2xca\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pyqtbuild\project.py", line 70, in apply_user_defaults
        super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "C:\Users\97152\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-5j8h2xca\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py", line 225, in apply_user_defaults
        self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "C:\Users\97152\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-5j8h2xca\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pyqtbuild\builder.py", line 66, in apply_user_defaults
        raise PyProjectOptionException('qmake',
    sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3a/fb/eb51731f2dc7c22d8e1a63ba88fb702727b324c6352183a32f27f73b8116/PyQt5-5.14.1.tar.gz#sha256=2f230f2dbd767099de7a0cb915abdf0cbc3256a0b5bb910eb09b99117db7a65b (from https://pypi.org/simple/pyqt5/) (requires-python:>=3.5). Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\97152\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' 'C:\Users\97152\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\97152\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpzk3hpkso' Check the logs for full command output.
```

how can I fix this I have installed the Microsoft C++ buildtools and tried downloading It using the pyqt5 wheel file (gives me a this file is not a supported wheel on this platform

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare\_metadata\_for\_build\_wheel' for PyQt5 5.15.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65447314/attributeerror-module-sipbuild-api-has-no-attribute-prepare-metadata-for-bui)

Answer (score 2):

Please, try:

1. Download file PyQt5-5.15.4-cp36.cp37.cp38.cp39-none-win_amd64.whl from the page
   https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5/#files
2. Rename it to PyQt5-5.15.4-py3-none-win_amd64.whl
3. Run pip install PyQt5-5.15.4-py3-none-win_amd64.whl

I was able to install it into Python 3.10 virtual environment, then was able to run example from https://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/firstprograms/

Comment: Thank you Andrew.  I banged my head on this topic for a long while before stumbling upon your answer.  I didn't realize the file needed to be renamed.  "I didn't get the memo."

Comment: Additionally, 5.15.5 will be released soon, but you can download it from https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pypi/