# Installation Error while installing pyqt-tools

Tags: python

I am trying to install `PyQt6`, in my cmd, when I run `pip install pyqt6` its just works fine but when I try to install `pip install pyqt-tools` its shows this error:

```
C:\Users\lenovo>pip install pyqt6-tools
Collecting pyqt6-tools
  Using cached pyqt6_tools-6.1.0.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
Collecting python-dotenv
  Using cached python_dotenv-0.19.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
Collecting pyqt6==6.1.0
  Using cached PyQt6-6.1.0.tar.gz (946 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [29 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 156, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          hook = backend.prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
      AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'

      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 345, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 160, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
        File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-omd2bkc3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\api.py", line 51, in build_wheel
          project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('pep517')
        File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-omd2bkc3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\abstract_project.py", line 83, in bootstrap
          project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
        File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-omd2bkc3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py", line 594, in setup
          self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4y93vt9z\pyqt6_e010daa9e104413b87d1d41abf25351d\project.py", line 60, in apply_user_defaults
          super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-omd2bkc3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pyqtbuild\project.py", line 70, in apply_user_defaults
          super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-omd2bkc3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py", line 241, in apply_user_defaults
          self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-omd2bkc3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pyqtbuild\builder.py", line 67, in apply_user_defaults
          raise PyProjectOptionException('qmake',
      sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

**I'm on `22.0.3 pip` version and `3.10 python` version**

Comment: I think this is quite related question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65447314/attributeerror-module-sipbuild-api-has-no-attribute-prepare-metadata-for-bui

Comment: uh, yes but that doesn't have have any answers

Comment: @VanshKhera pyqt-tools [does not support python-3.10](https://github.com/altendky/pyqt-tools/issues/98). You must use python-3.9 instead.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Qt6 needs to be installed on the OS before python package:

```
brew install pyqt5
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/qt5/bin:$PATH"
```

The path update is the key as the builder is not finding something that the qmake needs.