# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyQt6-Qt6>=6.3.0 (from pyqt6) (from versions: none)

Tags: pip, pyqt6

I have not managed to install PyQt6 in a few days to this error message:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyQt6-Qt6>=6.3.0 (from pyqt6) (from versions: none)
```

It happens when I install like this:

`python -m pip install --index-url https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pypi/simple/ PyQt6`

If I instead install without `--index-url`, it fails on installing the build depenencies with the following error message:

`AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'`

PyQt6 itself seems to be properly located and downloaded from pip. However, it then automatically tries to also find PyQt6-Qt6 and that does not work. What am I missing?

Python 3.9.7, pip 22.1.2, setuptools 62.3.2.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the version of `pip` you advertise? It seems to be a common error when using outdated versions (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65447314/attributeerror-module-sipbuild-api-has-no-attribute-prepare-metadata-for-bui)