# Travis: Can't import PyQt5 but python3-pyqt5 is installed

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, travis-ci

I assume my problem depends on the fact that I don't totally understand how TravisCI work.

The Python unittests on Travis raising an `ImportError` because of `import PyQt5`.

So I was modifying the `.travis.yml` in several ways and none of them works. All with the same result.

I used the `install-before` and the `install` section.
There i tried `sudo apt install python3-pyqt5` (which I would prefer).
And I tried `pip install pyqt5` and `pip install -U pyqt5`.

Travis use Ubuntu 20 LTS. I also installed this on a VM and checked out. A simple
`sudo apt python3-pyqt5` and I can `import PyQt5` without problems. So I assume on TravisCI something is different from a usual Ubuntu 20.

I am confused. Maybe this has something todo with the virtenv or another
part of Travis. Any ideas?

The original `.travis.yml` I used can be found in [this PR](https://github.com/buhtzz/backintime/pull/4) and including the different versions (see the commits).

#### Additional information's

I really need to avoid installing `PyQt5` via `pip` because this causing problems on `ppc64le` architecture where `PyQt5` can not be build. For example see [AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel' for PyQt5 5.15.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65447314/4865723)

Comment: The pip method is the currently supported one (except for building locally), if you have troubling with that under a specific architecture, consider writing to the [mailing list](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/mailman/listinfo/pyqt), which is followed by the official maintainer.

Comment: Do you have a link to proof that `apt` is not recommended in TravisCI environment?

Comment: I'm talking about the officially supported method of installing PyQt, the fact that *another* project requires a different installation procedure for it is a completely different (and unrelated) aspect.

Comment: THen again. OK, then where can I find the "officially supported method of installing PyQt" on **PowerPC** architecture?

Comment: As said, if it's for a specific architecture that isn't part of the standard ones, consider writing to the mailing list or to the maintainers for that architecture on that distro.