# How to install opentele~=1.15.1 python library

Tags: python, pip, libraries

pip install opentele~=1.15.1 gives me a mountain of errors in terminal

> $ pip install opentele~=1.15.1                                                                  Collecting opentele~=1.15.1                                                                                               Using cached opentele-1.15.1-py3-none-any.whl (81 kB)                                                                 Collecting telethon                                                                                                       Using cached Telethon-1.29.3.tar.gz (548 kB)                                                                            Installing build dependencies ... done                                                                                  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done                                                                              Preparing wheel metadata ... done                                                                                   Collecting pyqt5                                                                                                          Using cached PyQt5-5.15.9.tar.gz (3.2 MB)                                                                               Installing build dependencies ... done                                                                                  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done                                                                              Preparing wheel metadata ... error                                                                                      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:                                                                           command: /usr/bin/python3 /tmp/tmp4do0snl8 prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpz5tw6zi4                                cwd: /tmp/pip-install-m8brgluu/pyqt5                                                                               Complete output (31 lines):                                                                                             Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                        File "/tmp/tmp4do0snl8", line 126, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel                                                    hook = backend.prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel                                                                     AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'                                                                                                                                                       During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:                                                                                                                                                                             Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                        File "/tmp/tmp4do0snl8", line 280, in                                                                             main()                                                                                                                File "/tmp/tmp4do0snl8", line 263, in main                                                                                json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])                                                                 File "/tmp/tmp4do0snl8", line 130, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel                                                    return _get_wheel_metadata_from_wheel(backend, metadata_directory,                                                    File "/tmp/tmp4do0snl8", line 159, in _get_wheel_metadata_from_wheel                                                      whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)                                               File "/tmp/pip-build-env-f0u4y96i/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sipbuild/api.py", line 46, in build_wheel           project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('wheel',                                                                          File "/tmp/pip-build-env-f0u4y96i/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sipbuild/abstract_project.py", line 87, in bootstrap                                                                                                                        project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)                                                                      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-f0u4y96i/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 586, in setup            self.apply_user_defaults(tool)                                                                                        File "/tmp/pip-install-m8brgluu/pyqt5/project.py", line 68, in apply_user_defaults                                        super().apply_user_defaults(tool)                                                                                     File "/tmp/pip-build-env-f0u4y96i/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyqtbuild/project.py", line 70, in apply_user_defaults                                                                                                                      super().apply_user_defaults(tool)                                                                                     File "/tmp/pip-build-env-f0u4y96i/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 237, in apply_user_defaults                                                                                                                      self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)                                                                                File "/tmp/pip-build-env-f0u4y96i/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyqtbuild/builder.py", line 69, in apply_user_defaults                                                                                                                      raise PyProjectOptionException('qmake',                                                                             sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException                                                                             ----------------------------------------                                                                            ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 /tmp/tmp4do0snl8 prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpz5tw6zi4 Check the logs for full command output.

and tried 1000 times always no way to install this library same errors

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare\_metadata\_for\_build\_wheel' for PyQt5 5.15.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65447314/attributeerror-module-sipbuild-api-has-no-attribute-prepare-metadata-for-bui)

Comment: answered under your comment

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error code we see the following:

> AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'

Now that we narrowed down the issue, we can use the solution suggested here by @esqew:

[AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel' for PyQt5 5.15.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65447314/attributeerror-module-sipbuild-api-has-no-attribute-prepare-metadata-for-bui)

Which is updating `pip`:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Then we can install `opentele`:

```
pip install opentele
```

Comment: no way ... errors

Comment: Can you be more specific on what happened?