# Unsure what i'm doing wrong while installing PyQT5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am attempting to install PyQt5 for the sake of running a program that I have, but I'm really bad at reading cote so I can't seem to figure out what i'm doing wrong. I'm using Python 3.8.

```
Collecting PyQt5
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4d/5d/b8b6e26956ec113ad3f566e02abd12ac3a56b103fcc7e0735e27ee4a1df3/PyQt5-5.15.10.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\stard\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' 'c:\users\stard\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\stard\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo8hmzyy0'
         cwd: C:\Users\stard\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-m9pon6sv\PyQt5
    Complete output (32 lines):
    pyproject.toml: line 7: using '[tool.sip.metadata]' to specify the project metadata is deprecated and will be removed in SIP v7.0.0, use '[project]' instead
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\stard\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 64, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        hook = backend.prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
    AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\stard\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 207, in <module>
        main()
      File "c:\users\stard\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 197, in main
        json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
      File "c:\users\stard\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 66, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        return _get_wheel_metadata_from_wheel(backend, metadata_directory,
      File "c:\users\stard\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 95, in _get_wheel_metadata_from_wheel
        whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
      File "C:\Users\stard\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-l5m4_3ce\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\api.py", line 46, in build_wheel
        project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('wheel',
      File "C:\Users\stard\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-l5m4_3ce\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\abstract_project.py", line 87, in bootstrap
        project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
      File "C:\Users\stard\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-l5m4_3ce\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py", line 587, in setup
        self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "project.py", line 68, in apply_user_defaults
        super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "C:\Users\stard\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-l5m4_3ce\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pyqtbuild\project.py", line 70, in apply_user_defaults
        super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "C:\Users\stard\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-l5m4_3ce\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py", line 237, in apply_user_defaults
        self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "C:\Users\stard\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-l5m4_3ce\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pyqtbuild\builder.py", line 69, in apply_user_defaults
        raise PyProjectOptionException('qmake',
    sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\stard\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' 'c:\users\stard\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\stard\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo8hmzyy0' Check the logs for full command output.
```

I've tried:

- pip3 install pyqt5

Comment: Did you try upgrading `pip`? See more details here- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65447314/attributeerror-module-sipbuild-api-has-no-attribute-prepare-metadata-for-bui

Comment: Please try upgrading both pip and setuptools before going for the installation of PyQT5: "pip install --upgrade pip setuptools"

Comment: https://www.b-list.org/weblog/2023/dec/07/pip-install-safely/